# Which is the best way to declare logger variable in java

Tags: java, logging

I just wantd to know which is the best way declare logger variable in java.
Following are some declaration.

```
1> private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ServiceImpl.class);

2> private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ServiceImpl.class);

3> private static final Logger LOGGER= Logger.getLogger(ServiceImpl.class);

4> private static Logger LOGGER= Logger.getLogger(ServiceImpl.class);
```

P.S I really appreciate if  anybody knows  another best alternative ways to declare looger variable.

Comment: Up to you, but you should go for the `final` versions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should a "static final Logger" be declared in UPPER-CASE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417190/should-a-static-final-logger-be-declared-in-upper-case)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I vote for **3**

```
 private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ServiceImpl.class);
```

It's `final` since you don't change it and it's in uppercase since it's a constant.

Comment: It shoud NOT be uppercase. "Java Coding Style Guide", "Google Java Style" say, that it should be lower case "logger".   It is beeing discussed here:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/1417190/603314

Answer (score 14):

All upper-case variable names are IMO out because you really aren't declaring/defining a constant but a static variable. Uppercase names are more suitable for "constants". That said, I'd personally go with the first approach.

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ServiceImpl.class);
```

Comment: I completely agree with your statement.  Plus when you have LOGGER, it seems like that variable is just screaming out at you for your attention which should not happen.

Answer (score 3):

I personally think `private static final Logger LOGGER= Logger.getLogger(ServiceImpl.class);` is the best way to go for semantic and performance reasons:

- your Log belongs to the class not to various instances of it, for this reason you should make it static
- it should be private because it's used internally by the class, it's not part of it's public API
- making it final two makes sense, first of because this states that the refference will not change (which is the case here) and second because final intance variables (especially static ones) can be better optimised for speed by the compiler and the JIT (more details  [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibm/library/i-tuning/?open))
- naming it all upper-case is really just a nice convention, that's how static variables are declared in Java, it's not really a must but it makes the code more readable

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the first option but it is matter of personal choice I guess.

Comment: but PMD rules says static final variable should be capital

Comment: @Raje: PMD is being intentionally obtuse in this case. Look at any static final field in a Java standard library class (E.g. `System`) which is not a "real" constant (i.e. not primitive or `String`). They don't use uppercase names for these variables.

Answer (score 0):

First one is best.I prefer logger to be `final` and `static`....

Comment: @abhutra : thanks for quick reply . but PMD rules says static final variable should be capital.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding of the java style guide, 'logger' is best.  'LOGGER' would be for a defined constant.

Furthermore, using 'final', should make it a bit faster.

Thus #1.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not to use such a variable in every class, but instead delegate this work to a static utility wrapper around slf4j, from [jcabi-log](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-log/):

```
Logger.debug(this, "some variable = %s", value);
```

Check this post as well: http://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/23/avoid-java-static-logger.html

Comment: Though that's a bit tricky to implement if you want to have the caller's file name and line in your log statements, as opposed to the position from your utility class. But it's actually doable by utilizing `org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger`.

Answer (score 0):

It is good programming practice to share a single logger object between all of the instances of a particular class and to use the same logger for the duration of the program, so we use `static` and `final` for loggers.

It is not recommended to use multiple loggers (poor logging practice) rather than logging levels.

I think that

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ServiceImpl.class);
```

is the better option.

Comment: All of the logger declarations in the question are already `static` and declared as one variable, the question is asking whether it should be `final` and named in `UPPER` or `lower`.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody here uses `LOG` or `log`? I have found it to be nicer in practice. (Surely I'm not the first one to work on a place where that's the standard, because `@Log4j` in Lombok generates a `log` field as well. Of course it's also static final. And BTW, that's the best way to declare that field... add a `@Log4j` annotation. Done.)

Answer (score 0):

`private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(NameClass.class.getName());`

Where logger is a final, settled variable should be defined in UPPER CASE.
While getLogger()  static method need String as an argument, name of class should also invoke .getName() of class.

Answer (score 0):

@Slf4j annotation can help with this.

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
@Slf4j
public class CustomClassName {
 void customMethod(){
  log.info("Shorthand logger annotation example");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For ease of use, I prefer using `slf4j` and would like to use as below.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceImpl.class);
```