# slf4j logging syntax

Tags: logging, slf4j

I've got 3 developers on a project who have different styles when writing to logs.  Which of these variations is best?

```
LOG.info("error = {}", errmsg);
LOG.info("error = ", errmsg);
LOG.info("error = " + errmsg);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
LOG.info("error = {}", errmsg);
```

Correct and best.

```
LOG.info("error = ", errmsg);
```

This is most likely wrong. Unless `errmsg` is an exception, it will never be logged.

```
LOG.info("error = " + errmsg);
```

This one is not performing as good as first. You'll run `String` concatenation every time you hit this line while in first case variable replacement occurs only if statement will actually be logged.

<sup>Some time ago [I blogged](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.no/2010/05/clean-code-clean-logs-log-exceptions.html) about different logging syntaxes in [slf4j](/questions/tagged/slf4j).</sup>

Comment: I guess the 2nd is used for exceptions, right?   e.g.      LOG.info("Error reading file", e);

Comment: @Pregnantmom: you're absolutely right! The `errmsg` made me believe this is not an exception. Corrected my answer.

Comment: Personally I prefer the third using string concatenation. As for performance, String concatenation can be faster:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925423/is-it-better-practice-to-use-string-format-over-string-concatenation-in-java

Comment: Agree, `LOG.info("error = {}", errmsg);` should be used. No other options should be considered. Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555409/logger-slf4j-advantages-of-formatting-with-instead-of-string-concatenation

Answer (score 3):

This is the best ([jcabi-log](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-log/) on top of SLF4J):

```
Logger.info(this, "error=%s", errmsg);
```

It's a short alternative to:

```
private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Foo.class);
LOG.info(String.format("error=%s", errmsg));
```

First, it's convenient to let one utility class to take care about loggers instantiation. Second, it's very convenient to use `String.format()` for text formatting, because you always see the whole string and can easily translate it.

Answer (score 2):

An alteration of the first form is the best

```
log.info("error={}", errmsg);
```

As others have said, the second example has to be a mistake as there is no format token to insert `errmsg` into `"error = "`, unless `errmsg` is a `Throwable` and `info` level logging is enabled. Then the logger will print a stracktrace.

For many years I preferred the string concatenation, the third form. I found it easier to read months or years later when I go back to read the code.

However, as [Tomasz Nurkiewicz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/605744/tomasz-nurkiewicz) answered, the first form `LOG.info("error={}", errmsg);` is the best. The reason, though, isn't that `String.format()` is faster than String concatenation. It isn't. See [Is it better practice to use String.format over string Concatenation in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925423/is-it-better-practice-to-use-string-format-over-string-concatenation-in-java).

The reason the first form performs better is that if the `info` level logging is disabled, then the logging framework doesn't have to call  `errmsg.toString()`  and it doesn't have to execute `String.format()` at all. The only case where `errmsg.toString()` has no performance cost is if `errmsg` is a `String`.

I also would suggest no whitespace around the `=` as many log aggregators like Splunk will automatically index `error=errmsg` into a field and value pair. Also, if this truly is an error, then I would write it to the `error()` level, not `info()`. And most likely there is a `Throwable` exception somewhere before this code that should go into the `Throwable` parameter.

And, `logger`, while it is probably declared as `final`, is a mutable object, so, it should be in lower case. See [Should a "static final Logger" be declared in UPPER-CASE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417190/should-a-static-final-logger-be-declared-in-upper-case).

which means the answer really should be

```
log.info("error={}", errMsg, exception);
```

Comment: Interesting, since writing this answer, I now disagree with myself. updating

Answer (score 0):

Below is the exact copy paste from actual slf4j javadoc. Its worth visiting here :http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
 import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

 public class Wombat {

   final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Wombat.class);
   Integer t;
   Integer oldT;

   public void setTemperature(Integer temperature) {
     oldT = t;
     t = temperature;
     logger.debug("Temperature set to {}. Old temperature was {}.", t, oldT);
     if(temperature.intValue() > 50) {
       logger.info("Temperature has risen above 50 degrees.");
     }
   }
 }
```