# Should I use static method or static fields

Tags: java, multithreading, static

I want to declare some static variables and use them a lot in my code, so in this example if I want to change the phone number I will change it in one place:

```
public class AppInformation{
    static String phone_number="44444444";
}
```

So now I could get the phone_number by calling the class :
`AppInformation.phone_number`;

Another solution:

```
public class AppInformation {

    public static String get_phone_number(){
        return "44444444";
    } 
}
```

Now I could call the method:
`AppInformation.get_phone_number`();

Actually I prefer the second method because it is thread safe!

Is this correct? Are there any other suggestions?

Comment: If the program doesn't change the number, the first one is thread-safe - although you can't prove it's thread-safe just by looking at it, which you can with the second. If the program does change the number, the second one won't work.

Comment: so I should declare it as private static final string PHONE_NUMBER ! as mention below .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare it as `public static final String PHONE_NUMBER = "44444444"`. Since you can only read this variable, it is thread-safe.

Why I named it `PHONE_NUMBER`, not `phoneNumber` (or breaking all known to me Java conventions `phone_number`), is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417190/should-a-static-final-logger-be-declared-in-upper-case).

Comment: @user3516596 Without `final` threads can write to it (and later read from it). If you do not provide any synchronization - it's not (thread) safe.

Comment: should i declare it as public or private ?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare it as

static final String phone_number="44444444";
And do not worry about threadsafe anymore :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are saying is that you want a constant, which in Java, is commonly expressed like this:

```
public class AppInformation
{
  public static final String PHONE_NUMBER = "44444444";
}
```

Note, in your example you've missed:

- the [access modifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html), which in the case of a class means the value would be package private.
- the `final` keywork, which means the value could be modified when the program is running.

Comment: should I declare it as public or private ?\

Comment: Depends on where you want it to be visible - if `PHONE_NUMBER` is only used inside the class `AppInformation` then it should be `private`; however if you intend to use `PHONE_NUMBER` throughout your application then it should be `public`.  The same logic follows, for `protected` and *package private* (see the access modifier link I put in my answer)

Comment: yes thank you very much it is very helpful, so I think i will declare it as private ,because i just call it by the class them self, I mean AppInformation.PHONE_NUMBER . :)