# Resolve Java Checkstyle Error: Name 'logger' must match pattern '^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(_[A-Z0-9]+)*$'

Tags: java, eclipse, constants, checkstyle

Using the Eclipse Checkstyle plugin I see this error:

> Name 'logger' must match pattern `'^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(_[A-Z0-9]+)*$'`.

I resolved this error by changing:

`private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(someClass.class);`

to

`private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(someClass.class);`

**Why is this a checkstyle warning?**

Comment: Because your CheckStyle is configured to make it one?

Comment: @ChrisHayes True!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because the field is marked `final` and `static` which implies that it's a constant and should be named with uppercase letters.

From [this link](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_naming.html#Modules), you can see that the module `ConstantName` has the format `^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(_[A-Z0-9]+)*$` which is exactly the one your Checkstyle plugin has specified.

Comment: But `LOGGER` should be `logger` by Java naming convention so this is kind of a CheckStyle bug?

see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417190/should-a-static-final-logger-be-declared-in-upper-case).

Comment: @javaPlease42 It depends on how you define a constant. I don't think `logger` is a constant, so yes the rule doesn't really make sense here.

Comment: If it is static final then it should be considered as a constant and it should be  uppercase by Java naming convention.

Answer (score 5):

The [documentation](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_naming.html) recommends using this configuration if you wish to keep `logger` as a valid option:

```
<module name="ConstantName">
  <property name="format"
    value="^log(ger)?$|^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(_[A-Z0-9]+)*$"/>
</module>
```