# Rename the "log" logger to comply with the format "LOG(?:GER)?"

Tags: logging, intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarlint

I am trying to check the code quality with [sonarlint](http://www.sonarlint.org/intellij/).Above problem synopsis, I can't understand why should it says to make it to uppercase.But [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417190/should-a-static-final-logger-be-declared-in-upper-case) is against the above suggestion.Which one should be considered as correct one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has no right answer as this is a convention. Moreover it is subject to debate about what should be considered as constant (is it enough to have static final or should it be also immutable ?).

As you cannot configure this rule from sonarLint, I think it should not be a rule activated by default hence this jira ticket : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1385

Comment: Thank you for resolving this

Comment: is there any solution to this if we cannot disable the rule?